# test statistic for Spearman rank correlation

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

my problem is that I have calculated Spearman rank correlations between two variables. One reviewer asked me if I could add also test statistics for all coefficients where p < 0.001.

Here is one result:

```
> cor.test(pl$data, pl$rang, method= "spearman")


#       Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  pl$data and pl$rang
S = 911164.6, p-value = 1.513e-05
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0 
sample estimates:
rho 
-0.3347658
```

Is the test statistics equal to **S = 911164.6**? Is it OK that it is so big number?
Sorry in advance if the question is not very professional but I spend quite some time searching for the answers in the books and on internet. :(
Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: presumably it is the sum of squared rank differences (see the Wikipedia entry on Spearman rank correlation); its magnitude signifies just that you have a big data set, I think ...

Comment: so if someone ask from me to write also test statistics I could write S = 911164.6 and rho= -0,335?

Comment: @MtS I flagged your question to be migrated to stats.stackexchange.com but it was declined. You might want to go to that site yourself and ask them about your large S value, though BenBolker and RichieCotton have basically answered the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  The `?cor.test` help page (in the Value section) describes the return value from `cor.test` as:

> ```
>  A list with class ‘"htest"’ containing the following components:
> ```
>
> statistic: the value of the test statistic.

Adapting the example on that page, we see

```
x <- c(44.4, 45.9, 41.9, 53.3, 44.7, 44.1, 50.7, 45.2, 60.1)
y <- c( 2.6,  3.1,  2.5,  5.0,  3.6,  4.0,  5.2,  2.8,  3.8)
(result <- cor.test(x, y, method = "spearman"))
#         Spearman's rank correlation rho

# data:  x and y 
# S = 48, p-value = 0.0968
# alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0 
# sample estimates:
# rho 
# 0.6 
result$statistic
#  S 
# 48
```

The statistic is given by `(n ^ 3 - n) * (1 - r) / 6` where `n` is the length of `x` and `r <- cor(rank(x), rank(y))`.

Comment: Thanks you for this quick answer. So it is OK that my S is 911164? What could be the reason for so high number?

Comment: @MtS That specific statistics question might be better suited to http://stats.stackexchange.com/ rather than here, which is focused on coding.

Comment: Ben is it possible to copy the question to this other side?

Comment: @MtS: Read my updated answer.  `S` is large because you have a lot of data, and `S` is proportional to the length of the input vectors cubed.

Comment: in wikipedia I found that it is possible to test the significance with: rho*sqrt((n-2)/1-rho^2) or 0.6*sqrt((9-2)/1-0.6^2) = 1.546. This is not the test statistic? :(

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I have found is on the page: [Rpubs Spearman Rank Correlation](https://rpubs.com/aaronsc32/spearman-rank-correlation)

This question is also on [Cross Validated "Interpreting the Spearman's Rank Correlation Coefficient output in R. What is 'S'?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226069/interpreting-the-spearmans-rank-correlation-coefficient-output-in-r-what-is-s/467528#467528)

While the forumla `(n ^ 3 - n) * (1 - r) / 6`, were `n` is equal to the sample size of variables and `r` is equal to the correlation coefficient (rho) for calculting the S statistic is clear, there is no clear explaination on how to interpret the results. I have yet to find a clear answer :(